Dividing shape into 2 congruent pieces
How do I divide this shape into 2 congruent polygons?

Source: Penrose Tiles to Trapdoor Ciphers...and the Return of Dr. Matrix by Martin Gardner, Chapter 12 (no solutions in the book though).

If the shapes don't have to be connected, there are many obvious solutions, e.g., fcyvg gur jubyr funcr va bqq naq rira yvarf.

One solution that follows the grid lines:

 



 ⬜⬜⬜⬜
 ⬜⬜⬜⬜
 ⬜⬜⬜⬜
 ⬜⬜⬜⬜

Alternative representation (for browsers/fonts that don't display Unicode U+1F7E5 or U+1F7E6 correctly):

 2222222
2233332
2222232
 3333232
 0003230
 0003230
 0003330
 0003330


+1 Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)! Your solution is nicely displayed.

The question asks for congruent pieces. The two pieces here are mirror images.

@fljx Congruence covers shapes that are identical by reflection: "two sets of points are called congruent if, and only if, one can be transformed into the other by an isometry, i.e., a combination of rigid motions, namely a translation, a rotation, and a reflection."

The 40 characters which you use to represent the original shape are indistinguishable (in Google Chrome). Please use two characters which are distinguishable without the need for any trickery like obscure character-sets.

@RosieF I can see the difference: https://i.sstatic.net/e85VwqVv.png
